# C# Using Constructors to Find Opposite of an Integer

Tags: c#, methods, constructor

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to write the opposite of a number using constructors. The goal of the program is simply to read a number from input and to use a constructor to return the opposite of that number. I am aware that I could just multiple by -1 in the main code but I am trying to teach myself constructors.

My code is as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool done = false;
        while (!done)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number to find the opposite of : ");
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Opposite opposite = new Opposite(number);
            Console.WriteLine(number);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}

public class Opposite
{
    public Opposite(int x)
    {
        x = x * (-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to learn with this exercise? I fail to see the relationship between the use of constructors and the specific "opposite problem". Do you want "number" to contain it's opposite after calling the constructor?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=c%23+beginners.  Sincerely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your doing now is only modifying the local copy of x within the constructor. If you want to use the changed value you should add a field and assign the result to that. You can then access the field of your newly constructed object for the opposite number. The key here is the int is only passed in by value, the variable itself is unchanged

Comment: So something like public int newnumber; outside the constructor, and inside the constructor newnumber = x * (-1); and then WriteLine newnumber

Comment: Yes within the class, and assign x*-1 to that within the constructor. Then when you want the opposite use the newly created instance to get your number

Comment: You'll want to write opposite.newnumber

Comment: Yep. Did so. I will mark your post as the answer after the wait time. Thanks a bunch!